# my custom widget does not work with Listview.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create badge for last two days but not getting success

A container and a small container for badge like..

If main container's circle is 200 than i want badge circle 50 and its stack positions like -25 top and -25 right

its working fine but when i use this customWidget inside listview builder its showing Contstraint width or height error

so how to code my customWidget so that it works with all way...

[image]

here is my code

```
 return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          child: CustomWidget(
            number: 1,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20,),

        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: CustomWidget(
            number: 1,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20,),

        Container(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return CustomWidget(number: index);
          }),
        )

      ],
    )));
```

```
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;

  const CustomWidget({Key? key,required this.number,}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          double width=constraints.maxWidth;
          double height=constraints.maxHeight;
         return  Container(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            // color: Colors.red,
            child: Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
                  ),
                  child: Center(child: Text('Widget Detail',),),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: -1*(width/8),
                  right: -1*(width/8),
                  child: Container(
                    width: width/4,
                    height: height/4,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(width: 2,color: Colors.black)
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text(number.toString(),style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,fontSize: 16
                    ),),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },

      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` is in horizontal direction, but in `CustomWidget` you set the width to `constraints.maxWidth`. `ListView` is meant to be scrollable, so Flutter doesn't know how to size your widget, as the maximum width for something scrollable to the horizontal axis is infinity.

If you're trying to make `CustomWidget` square, just like the `Container` above it, set `width` to `constraints.maxHeight` instead.

```dart
return LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    double width=constraints.maxHeight; // change this
    double height=constraints.maxHeight;
    return  Container(
...
```

[image: CustomWidget screenshot]